# Bulk inserts with EF4.2

Tags: performance, entity-framework-4.1

We have a huge performance problem in our app, we collect data from different systems and save it in our DB to later generate some reports.

We use Entity framework 4.2 and DbSets, is there a better way of doing bulk inserts then the Add method for each entity on the DbSet? Because there are huge performance problems with the Add logic

```
oneThousandCustomers.Foreach(c => context.Customers.Add(c)); //This will take a minute
context.SaveChanges(); //This takes under a second
```

I guess the add method is doing lots lookups etc and stuff under the hood, but I just want to bulk insert this data. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the deal here is that EF does a whole lot of stuff under the scenes when you add an item to a collection.

The really big thing in terms of performance is that it calls DetectChanges() automatically on each add command which enumerates the entire object graph.

What this means is that if you have a large amount of items which are being tracked by the current EF context this will cause some really serious performance issues.

Heres some tips to improve performance, as a comparison i can insert 1000 fairly simple entities with no FK's to EF in under 1/2 a second.

- Make sure you are using a new EF context instance for your query,
  this will ensure that your change graph is small so add will be
  fairly quick.
- Turn of auto change detection for the DbContext

Code to turn off auto-detect changes

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

When disabling AutoDetectChanges you need to be a little careful as it means that most of the EF automagic is turned off so you may get some weirdness especially if you are using navigation properties or are updating existing entities. To solve these issues call DetectChanges just before you call SaveChanges. This will decrease performance and isn't needed with simple add operations so in your example you can probably get away without this.

This MSDN article talks about this, (note even though its EF 5 its the same in 4) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696177%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Comment: We use a CQRS framework and the context is injected per Request, changing behavior of the context is a bit dangerous since there is no guarantee that other parts of the Command-logic will NOT use the context after you have change the contexts behavior.

Comment: Performance is dangerous and involves compromises, if you want the benefits of EF then you need to either live with the performance issues or manually manage the context to optimize performance. If you don't want to do this and you also want performance then dont use EF. However I do exactly the same thing with CQRS, messaging and  bulk imports and EF (for both query and write) and it works fine.

Comment: We choose this one because it was so easy to change our existing code into it. All Unit tests and Scenario tests are green so it looks like its working! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [LinqEntityDataReader](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/LinqEntityDataReader) to perform SqlBulkCopy on the entity collection which will improve the performance enter link description herein your application.